# How to "do something" on Swing component resizing?

Tags: java, swing

I've a class which extends `JPanel`. I overwrote `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

There is a variable which has to be recalculated when the panel's dimensions change. How do I do that in a proper way?

Comment: Is the calculation long/time consuming?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly then you should read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Component Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) which shows you how to listen for a change in a components size.

Answer (score 45):

Like Adam Paynter suggested, you can also add an inner class to your code, like this:

```
class ResizeListener extends ComponentAdapter {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            // Recalculate the variable you mentioned
        }
}
```

The code you have entered between the innermost brackets will be executed everytime the component get resized.

Then you add this listener to your component with

```
myJPanel.addComponentListener(new ResizeListener());
```

You can get your component by using `e.getComponent()`. This way you can call any method of your component from inside the inner class like

```
e.getComponent().getWeight();
```

Answer (score 21):

I suppose you could override the various `setSize` and `resize` methods and perform the calculation there. However, you may not find all the places where the size can be changed. You may want to have your class implement [ComponentListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) and simply listen to itself for resize events.

**Warning:** I am not a Swing expert.

**Warning:** I have not compiled this code.

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel implements ComponentListener {

    public MyJPanel() {
        this.addComponentListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Paint, paint, paint...
    }

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        // Perform calculation here
    }

    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

}
```

Comment: However, if the component is resized, but it isn't being painted, you may not wanna re calculate anything yet

Comment: +1 for showing all the methods you have to implement for the ComponentListener so I didn't need to look them up myself ;)

Answer (score 7):

If the calculation isn't time consuming, I would just re-calculate the value each time in `paintComponent()`.

Otherwise, you can save a value that is the size of the component and check it against the new size in `paintComponent`.  If the size changed, then recalculate, otherwise don't.

```
private Dimension size;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if (!size.equals(getSize())){
        size = getSize();
        // recalculate value
    }
}
```

Or, you can do the calculation on a resize event.

```
//in the constructor add the line
addComponentListener(resizeListener);

private ComponentListener resizeListener = new ComponentAdapter(){
    public void componentResized(ActionEvent e){
        // recalculate value
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to implement a [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html):

```
myjpanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        //recalculate variable
    }
});
```

Here, I have used a [`ComponentAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentAdapter.html) because I only intend on overriding `componentResized()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use (where CoordinatePlane is a JPanel):

**I'm not an expert**

```
public CoordinatePlane() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            //YOUR CODE HERE         
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This simple example is drawing a red circle in the resized frame....

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class RedCircle extends JFrame implements ComponentListener {
     int getWidth;
     int getHeight;
     
      public RedCircle() {
        super("Red Circle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentListener(this);             
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            getWidth = e.getComponent().getWidth();
            getHeight = e.getComponent().getHeight();
            
            Panel pane = new Panel(getWidth,getHeight);
            
            add(pane);
      }
    
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         RedCircle rc = new RedCircle();
    }
    

 
 public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
       
    }

    
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
     
    }

    
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    
    }


}


class Panel extends JPanel {
    int panelWidth;
    int panelHeight;
    
    public Panel(Integer getWidth,Integer getHeight) {
       
    panelWidth = getWidth;
    panelHeight = getHeight;
    
    }
    
public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
        super.paintComponent(comp);
        Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
       
        int realWidth = panelWidth - 17;
        int realHeight = panelHeight - 40;
       
        float Height = (realHeight);
        float Width = (realWidth);
        
    // draw the Red Circle
        comp2D.setColor(Color.red);
        Ellipse2D.Float redCircle = new Ellipse2D.Float(0F, 0F, Width, Height);
        comp2D.fill(redCircle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It resizes automatically if it's

1. inside a BorderLayout panel and
2. put there as BorderLayout.CENTER component.

If it doesn't work, you probably have forgotten one of these two.