# How to autoresize Swing and JavaFX application components from a Stage IntelliJ

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a Java application, where the main frame is a Stage from JavaFX, and the components I have inside are Swing components added to this stage. I have JButtons, JLabels, JPanels, some JavaFX TextAreas, etc...

This application must be able to et the size of its components according to the screen resolution, but I've tried to retrieve the screen size to use it to set the size of the components according to this resolution like this, but didn't worked for me:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setWidth_percentage(screenSize.getWidth() / 1920.0);
setHeight_percentage(screenSize.getHeight() / 1080.0);
```

These two functions are just to have a reference of the screen size. As my screen is 1920x1080 and I am developing the components according to my resolution, I am using a percentage to set the width and height of the components according to that percentage:

```
private static void setWidth_percentage(double width_percentage_) {
    width_percentage = width_percentage_;
    System.out.println("Width_percentage: " + width_percentage);
}

private static void setHeight_percentage(double height_percentage_) {
    height_percentage = height_percentage_;
    System.out.println("Height_percentage: " + height_percentage);
```

As my components look correctly with my screen resolution, the logic I am using here is that, for example, if the screen resolution where the application is going to be installed is half of my resolution screen, the components will be half of the size they have on my screen. Here is an example of how I try to set the size of the jbuttons:

```
private Image scaleImage(Image imageButton) {
    return imageButton.getScaledInstance((int) Math.round(((BufferedImage) imageButton).getWidth() * InterfaceControlsManager.getWidth_percentage()),
            (int) Math.round(((BufferedImage) imageButton).getHeight() * InterfaceControlsManager.getHeight_percentage()),
            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
}
```

This function means that if the image of the JButton is, lets say, 100x100 with my screen resolution (1920x1080), in a screen with half of that resolution, will be 50x50. I am doing this for the buttons because the size of the JButton corresponds to the size of the image.

When trying to resize the JPanels, I am doing this:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double screenWidth = screenSize.getWidth();
double screenHeight = screenSize.getHeight();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.round(screenWidth * 0.8), (int) Math.round(screenHeight * 0.7)));
```

Here I am using the screen resolution to set the size of the JPanel, so if the screen resolution is 1920x1080, this panel must have a height of (1080 * 0.7). For me this must works in any screen resolution, but when I change the resolution of my screen, or I try the aplication in other screens with different resolutions, I am not getting the expected result. Also, I realized that this function: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` is not always retriving the current screen resolution correctly, so I thought another approach by using the DisplayMode instead of that like this:

```
DisplayMode displayMode = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode();
double screenWidth = displayMode.getWidth();
double screenHeight = displayMode.getHeight();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.round(screenWidth * 0.8), (int) Math.round(screenHeight * 0.7)));
```

I can see how the DisplayMode ALWAYS retrieve the correct resolution screen (I don't understand why `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` doesn't). But I am having the same issue when changing the resolution of my screen or when installing the application in other PCs with other resolution screens. To put an example, if the panel must have the 90% of the screen height, it paints (with a different resolution screen of 1920x1080) the height of the panel with the 70% of the screen height.

My last approach was to use the size of the application frame, in this case, a Stage, because all the Swing components are wrapped in a JavaFX stage.

In the way I've coded the application, it first builds all the components, giving all the size to all the components, and after they are added to the Stage, and the Stage is shown. But I've realized that the size of the Stage is not given until it is shown, so I cannot use the size of the Stage during the components creation, because they are made before the `stage.show()` line.

During my search, I've read about this [How to add a window resize listener to JavaFX scene](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/11/adding-a-window-resize-listener-to-javafx-scene/), but the scene, in my case, is built after the components, so I have the same problem as with the Stage size. Here the code where I am creating the Scene and the Stage:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "FX and Swing thread should be merged. Are you using Java 8 and the javafx.embed.singleThread flag?");
        }

        //Add Swing view and interface components to the FX frame
        SwingNode viewNode = addSwingNodeToFXFrame(primaryStage);
        //----------------------------------------------

        // Auxiliary panel with provisional content
        Accordion auxiliaryPanelFX = new Accordion();

        // Do the lay-out using FX
        HBox hbox = new HBox(viewNode, auxiliaryPanelFX);
        HBox.setHgrow(viewNode, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Show the window
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hbox));
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FXApp");
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
        setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
        System.out.println("Frame size: " + primaryStage.getWidth() + ", " + primaryStage.getHeight());

    } catch (IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        database.insertSystemErrorLog(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),ex);
    }

}
```

I've also read about `ComponentAdapter` and `ResizeListener`, here is the link: [How to “do something” on Swing component resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088595/how-to-do-something-on-swing-component-resizing), but I can only use them with Swing components, and in my case, I want to know the size of the Stage after it is built to set the size of the Swing components according to its size.

There is a way that I didn't investigate to resize an application made with a Stage, and with Swing components in it, according to the screen resolution. There is nothing developed about resizing an application which mix JavaFX and Swing components?

Sorry for the lenght of the question, I tried to be as much specific I could. Thanks for any help!

Daniel.

**UPDATED WITH A minimal reproducible example**:
Launcher:

```
package src;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class LauncherTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("javafx.embed.singleThread", "true");
        Application.launch(ResizeStageTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

ResizeStageTest:

```
package src;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ResizeStageTest extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "false")) ||
                !Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty("sun.java2d.d3d", "true"))) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Do not change the Direct3D default settings (Windows specific), "
                    + "it may cause glitches during frame re-sizing.");
        }

        Application.launch(args);
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "FX and Swing thread should be merged. Are you using Java 8 and the javafx.embed.singleThread flag?");
        }

        SwingNode viewNode = new SwingNode();
        addSwingNodeToFXFrame(viewNode);

        Accordion auxiliaryPanelFX = new Accordion();

        HBox hbox = new HBox(viewNode, auxiliaryPanelFX);
        HBox.setHgrow(viewNode, Priority.ALWAYS);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hbox));

        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addSwingNodeToFXFrame(SwingNode swingNode) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DisplayMode displayMode = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode();
            double screenWidth = displayMode.getWidth();
            double screenHeight = displayMode.getHeight();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.round(screenWidth * 0.5), (int) Math.round(screenHeight * 0.5)));
            panel.add(button);
            swingNode.setContent(panel);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**UPDATE 2: Differences between the appearance of the minimal reproducible example when displaying in a 1920x1080 screen resolution and in a 1366x768:**
1920x1080:
[image: 1920x1080]

1366x768:
[image: 1366x768]

Here you can see the main problem I have. Why the button of the 1920x1080 screen resolution looks bigger than the button in the picture of a 1366x768 resolution screen if I am using the screen resolution to set the size of the button? If I set the size of the button as:

```
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.round(screenWidth * 0.5), (int) Math.round(screenHeight * 0.5)));
```

Why don't both buttons look with the same size? This is the problem I have with my application. What can I do to display my application with the same appearance indepently of the screen resolution used?

Here is the difference in my application with one of the panels I am creating. The 1920x1080 image is the good one, the way it must be displayed (same resolution screen examples as before):
1920x1080:
[image: 1920x1080]

1366x768:
[image: 1366x768]

As you can see, in spite of I am using the `DisplayMode` class or the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();`, the panel is not displaying exactly the same in both screen resolutions. What I need to know is how can I display my components in the Stage (full screen mode) according to the current resolution screen to be able to see the application with the same appearance in any resolution screen. This is getting me crazy... :(

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions, please

Comment: sorry, don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: don't worry @kleopatra ! that's not my intention :), I simply didn't understand hehe.. I've searched about naming conventions and you're right, I should use that conventions for best practices. Got it!. And about my question, there is something that I can do to achieve what I am looking for? Thanks in advance!

Comment: **"**_the components I have inside are Swing components added to this stage_**"** may I ask why ? Why do you mix the two ?

Comment: Yes @c0der, it is because I am using a GIS library which also manage components in Swing. For now, I have to code almos everything in Swing and, when they finish their library using JavaFX, I have to recode the parts of the application where I use that library. They gave us the training using Swing, and my project decided to start using it instead of JavaFX until they release their new version for JavaFX.. it is a project requeriment  ¬¬... to start coding in Swing but wrapping the components into a Stage thinking that maybe in a near future the application will be released as an android app

Comment: Thank you. Can you post [mre] that shows the problem ?

Comment: @c0der Updated. You will see how changing the resolution of the screen, sometimes the look of the application is not the same. Sometimes the button is smaller, sometimes it corresponds to the dimension specified on the code. Also, if the application allow resizing by setting 'stage.setResizable(true);', I can't find the way to resize the components (Swing and JavaFX components in the application) according to the stage size. There is something to set properly the size of the components according to the resolution screen in full screen mode, and according to the stage size when it is resized?

Comment: How do you want the button to behave when parent is resized ? You can control this behavior by changing the layout manager of the JPanel (for example `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());` ). If needed override `getPreferredSize`

Comment: In the final release of the application, the main stage will never be resized, and the components inside of it willnever be resized independently. To resize the stage going out from the full screen mode will not be an option. The reason of my question is: How can I create all the components of my application according to the resolution of the screen. I've explained in the question what didn't worked for me, and I'd like to know if there is something I am missing when creating them, or if there is other way to set the size of the components according to that resolution. Can you help me?

Comment: @c0ded I've updated the question with two images to do this more visual

Comment: Really?? Nobody can help with this???? :(

Comment: Someone had to deal with this? I am not able to find anything on internet about this